CSES Introductory problem's algorithm - Increasing Array
I am working around to resolve CSES Introductory problem's algorithm - Increasing Array via c++. I need help, please.
You are given an array of n integers. You want to modify the array so that it is increasing, i.e., every element is at least as large as the previous element.
On each move, you may increase the value of any element by one. What is the minimum number of moves required?
Input
The first input line contains an integer n: the size of the array.
Then, the second line contains n integers x1, x2 ... xN the contents of the array.
Output

Print the minimum number of moves.

Example

Input: 5
3 2 5 1 7


Output: 5

My code is following
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iterator>  
#include <algorithm>  
#include <numeric>    
#include <sstream>
#include <charconv>
#include <cassert>
#include <iomanip>
#include <optional>
#include <string_view> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arrSize = 0;
    int number = -1;
    vector<int> vect;
    string s;

    std::string firstLine;
    std::getline(std::cin, firstLine);
    arrSize = stoi(firstLine); 

    std::string secondLine;
    std::getline(std::cin, secondLine);
    std::istringstream strm(secondLine);

    while (strm >> s)
    {
        std::istringstream(s) >> number;
        vect.push_back(number);
    }
    
    int cnt = 0; 
    
    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arrSize; j++)
        {
            int first = vect[i];

            int second = vect[j];

            if (first > second)
            {
                std::swap(vect[i], vect[j]); 
                cnt++;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << cnt;

    return 0;
}

For the one of test cases input data are

10
6 10 4 10 2 8 9 2 7 7

and the correct output is by test

31

but my code returns

18

I understand here the "move" is in fact a swap.  Cannot get the mistake...
Update #1
I've have tried different aproach like
int cnt = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < arrSize; ++i)
{
    if (vect[i] <= vect[i - 1])
    {
        cnt += vect[i - 1] - vect[i] + 1;
        int v = vect[i - 1] + 1;
        vect[i] = v;
        std::cout << vect[i] << "\t";
    }
} 

And get this result (
So I am incerasing the array but the correct output is  31.
I steel need help...


CS algorithms

You are solving an entirely different problem than the one you are supposed to sovle. You are counting how many swaps it takes to sort the array, while the question is how many increments it takes to make the array non-decreasing. The original problem is very simple, it can be solved in one pass, you don't even need to store the elements.

@IgorTandetnik Thanks man! Now I get whats the difference. Would be fantasic to see your solution as well.

Hint: each subsequent element is either greater than or equal to the previous high water mark (in which case you have the new high water mark) or is less than (in which case you have to increment it as many times as it takes to reach the high water mark).

@IgorTandetnik I see but pls check ny code I cannot get the correct output anyway.

In cnt += vect[i - 1] - vect[i] + 1 drop +1 at the end; and on the next line. The problem says "every element is at least as large" - that is, greater or equal. You don't have to make each subsequent element strictly larger than the previous, equal is good enough.

Note also that you don't need to actually store elements in a vector. On each iteration you only need the previous (after adjustments) and the current element - you can act on the value right after you read it, and forget it right away.
